# Windows Phone, Web Services and Catching Exceptions

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the following code in Windows Phone:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_LogIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Service1SoapClient web_service = new Service1SoapClient();
        web_service.LogInAsync(TextBox_Username.Text, TextBox_Password.Password);
        web_service.LogInCompleted += new EventHandler<LogInCompletedEventArgs>(login_complete);
    }

    private void login_complete(object obj, ClientWebService.LogInCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string answer = e.Result.ToString();

        if (answer.Equals("Success") || answer.Equals("success"))
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Authenticated.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The log-in details are invalid!");
        }
    }
}
```

The code makes use of a web service in order to log-in the user into the system.  The log-in system works as it should.

My question is, where should I insert the try catch statement in order to catch exception when the web service is NOT running?  I tried in the button_click event handler to no avail and even in the line when I am getting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what type your Service1SoapClient is based upon so the statements below may not be accurate. It doesn't appear that you're using the Mobile Services Client since you're passing in a username and password and returning some other state.

However, the `...Async` suffix on the `LoginAsync` method name indicates that this API returns a `Task<T>` which means that this API is built to be used by the new `async` and `await` keywords of C# 5.

Therefore, I recommend altering your code to read as follows:
```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

```
private async void Button_LogIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Service1SoapClient web_service = new Service1SoapClient();
        string answer = await web_service.LogInAsync(TextBox_Username.Text, TextBox_Password.Password);

        if (answer.ToLower().Equals("success"))
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Authenticated.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The log-in details are invalid!");
        }
    catch (<ExceptionType> e)
    {
        // ... handle exception here
    }
}
```

}
```

Note that one of the side-benefits of `async` and `await` is that they allow you to write your code logically, including your exception handling code which, prior to `async` and `await` was hard to get right!

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however my IDE is not recognizing async and await.  I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Matthew: What version of the .NET Framework is your project targeting?

Comment: The web service is targeting version 3.5.  On the other hand, the mobile app is targeting version 4.0

Comment: Ahhh. Is there any way you could upgrade your projects to support .NET 4.0+? That'll give you C# 5 and all its (wonderful) goodness.

Comment: That's what I am planning to do.  I made the web service for version 3.5 because there apparently was no option to do it in version 4.0.  I later discovered that in .NET version 4, you first have to create a web project and then manually add the web service using Add --> New Item

Comment: Awesome :) There just too much goodness in .NET FX 4+ to ignore it ;)